# Category $\text{Matr}$ with $\text{Obj(Matr)} = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$

Tags: category-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. I want to define a category $\text{Matr}$ with

1. $\text{Obj(Matr)} = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$
2. If $n$ and $m$ are two objects, then $\text{Hom}(n,m)$ is the set of all matrices $m \times n$ with entries from $R$.
3. Composition is the usual matrix multiplication.

The problem is that I don't really understand what to do when $n$ or $m$ is $0$. If I set $\text{Hom}(n,m) = \emptyset$ when $n$ xor $m$ is $0$ then what should I do with $\text{Hom}(0,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't set, say, $\mathrm{Hom}(5,0) = \emptyset$, as the matrices in this set should represent the $R$-linear mappings $R^5 \to R^0 = \{0\}$. This set should contain a single mapping, namely the 0 map.

Generally, whenever $n = 0 \lor m = 0$, you want $\mathrm{Hom}(n,m)$ to contain a unique element: the unique $n \times m$ matrix (without any entries), which represents the 0 mapping.

In particular, this makes the number 0 a so-called 0 object.

Comment: Hm..But if I have, say $n \neq 0$ and $m=0$, then any zero matrix $k \times n$ with $k \geq 1$ maps $R^n$ to ${0}$. So $\text{Hom(n, 0)}$ contains infinitely many elements, not one. Also, any matrix maps $0$ to $0$, so I do not understand why $\text{Hom}(0,0)$ contains only one element. Can you recommend some books where I can find more about this?

Comment: These matrices still need to have the appropriate dimensions in order to be composed. A $k \times n$ zero matrix produces, when given an $n$-vector, the $k$-dimensional vector with all zero entries. That does not lie in $R^0$. The space $R^0$ contains just one point: its own zero vector, which is actually a vector without any entries.

Comment: aa, of course! thanks!

Comment: @MeesdeVries that's interesting. So the product of an "empty matrix" $n \times 0$ and an "empty column" $0 \times 0$ is a zero vector $(0, 0, \dots , 0)$ in $R^{n}$? I also would like to know what books contain this example.

Comment: @Goodnighyn, yes, this is a natural consequence of the ordinary definition of matrix multiplication together with the ("correct") convention that the empty sum in an abelian group equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make any distinction when $n$ or $m$ equals $0$. Just recall that a $n\times m$-matrix in $R$ is a map 
$$
\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\times \{1,2,\ldots,m\}\to R.
$$
When either $n$ or $m$ equals $0$, the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\times \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ is empty. In such case, there exists a unique $n\times m$-matrix in $R$, given by the empty map to $R$.